# Spring boot + spring data dependencies doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cloud-stream

I'm running spring boot application with spring-cloud-stream and everything works just fine. When I added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The application couldn't start anymore and start throwing this exception:

```
2018-12-02 17:35:59,478 [main] ERROR [SpringApplication::reportFailure] - Application startup failed
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:67) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getConfigurationSource(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:58) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:354) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
        at com.App.main(App.java:14) [classes/:?]
```

This is the relevant parts from my pom file:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Ditmars.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to change the versions of the dependency but nothing worked. I would like to avoid upgrading major version for spring-boot or spring-data. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you use spring boot project you might have a dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And also if you use a parrent dependency you do not have to use manualy version to your dependencies:

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
 <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Comment: I try to use spring-boot-cassandra dependency and it resulted with the same error